# Form component created once and reused shares the same data

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a form component created once and reused twice shares the same data . Please have a look at the code

// sign in component shared

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SignInFormService } from '../../services/sign-in-form-create.service';
import { Auth } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in-form',
  templateUrl: './sign-in-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in-form.component.css']
})
export class SignInFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private auth: Auth) { }
  @Input() userType: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

createForm() {
  this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      username: '',
      password: ''
  });
}
```

// Code On editor
1.[This is an working example works fine without using service](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7mlgj?file=app/app.module.ts)
2. [This is not working when a service is used](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dny7sq?file=main.ts)

My question is that component why the component shares the same data when used with a service. How to still protect the component from sharing the data even when the service is used?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: do you wish to use service or not?

Comment: @yuruzi, Question updated. @ Deepak Jha, Yes

Comment: You can also look at the code on editor

Comment: You have one instance of service. Each of your component uses the same FormGroup. What are you expecting?

Comment: so how can I make it two instance.

Comment: Provide service on component

Comment: How? I don't understand.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azrptd?file=app/sign-in-form.component.ts

Comment: Maybe better solution would be not having formGroup property in service. Service will only return it

Comment: Thanks but why not having formGroup property in service?