# Form component created once and reused shares the same service

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How to prevent component (which is reused) from reusing the same service?
How to protect the reused component from sharing the data when the service is used?

### Code On editor

1- [This is an working example works fine without using service](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7mlgj?file=app/app.module.ts)

2- [This is not working when a service is used](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dny7sq?file=main.ts)

// sign in component shared

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SignInFormService } from '../../services/sign-in-form-create.service';
import { Auth } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in-form',
  templateUrl: './sign-in-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in-form.component.css']
})
export class SignInFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private auth: Auth) { }
  @Input() userType: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

createForm() {
  this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      username: '',
      password: ''
  });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483642/form-component-created-once-and-reused-shares-the-same-data

Comment: @yuruzi I don want to use the service within the component.

Comment: This is module wide service

Comment: Your service should only return data For example https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms/blob/master/packages/core/src/service/dynamic-form.service.ts#L87

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. Can you explain me in brief?

Comment: Remove `public formGroup: FormGroup;` from service. It should be component property

Comment: why should it be?

Comment: If you use one formGroup from one instance of shared service then it will always be the same instance of formGroup

Comment: So this is the forgroup that creates the problem. So anyway if dynamically creating the formgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Angular services are singleton. If many components are using the same service, these components will have the same object reference, so if they are using service's variables, they are sharing same references.

In your demo, you are using the same `FormGroup` in two components, so values are changed everywhere.

There are many ways to fix it.

1. You could return a new instance of the `FormGroup` every time, instead of returning the instance stored in your service.
2. If you want to persist `FormGroups` in your service, you will have to keep them in a collection and manage instances.

The best way would be to use the `formBuilder` directly in components instead of services to avoid memory leaks, otherwise you will have to manage your instances

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-sign-in-form',
   templateUrl: './sign-in-form.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./sign-in-form.component.css']
})
export class SignInFormComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input() userType: string;
   formGroup: FormGroup;

   constructor(
       private formBuilder: FormBuilder
   ) {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
       this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
            username: '',
            password: ''
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: Based on your answer, I got some questions 
1.Can many components not use one service?
2.how can i keep them in collection and manage instance?
3.why formbuilder in service cause memory leaks?

Comment: 1- A service is always share. You can inject multiples services in a component. If you inject a service in multiples components, these components use the same service.
2- You can create a collection of objects containing your component (to retrieve it easily) reference and the `FormGroup` associated. You can store objects in an other object ( kind of dictionnary) or in an array.
3- If you don't delete `FormGroup` instances properly where they are no longer used

Comment: But as I mentionned in the answer, I suggest you to create and keep your `FormGroup` whitin the component

Comment: I need a way to seperate my formlogic from the components. Right now i can keep from logic  in a component as it is short but what if the form logic grows.

Comment: What if the multiple components use the same service? What do you mean by You can create a collection of objects containing your component (to retrieve it easily) reference and the FormGroup associated.